# Complex Variable Structure with Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am trying to figure out a complex variable structure with jinja2 template in Ansible. I have tried different solutions with dictsort and "if" loop inside "for" loop, but I do not see any progress. Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to print the `virtual_ro_id` based on the `ansible_hostname`. And hostnames are **server1.dc1.com** & **server2.dc1.com**, same for dc2 . The var file is given below.

```
datacenters:
  dc1:
    server1:
      - virtual_ro_id: "60"
    server2:
      - virtual_ro_id: "60"
  dc2:
    server1:
      - virtual_ro_id: "61"
    server2:
      - virtual_ro_id: "61"
```

This is what my template syntax looks like:

```
    {% for dc in lookup('dict', datacenters) %}
    {% set dc_name=ansible_fqdn.split(.)[1] %}
      {% if 'dc' == dc_name %}
        ID: {{ dc.ansible_hostname.virtual_ro_id }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I usually get syntax error or no value gets by the template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
server1.dc1.com
server2.dc1.com
server1.dc2.com
server2.dc2.com
```

the task

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: datacenters[mydomain][myhost][0]['virtual_ro_id']
      vars:
        myhost: "{{ inventory_hostname.split('.').0 }}"
        mydomain: "{{ inventory_hostname.split('.').1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [server1.dc1.com] => {
    "datacenters[mydomain][myhost][0]['virtual_ro_id']": "60"
}
ok: [server2.dc1.com] => {
    "datacenters[mydomain][myhost][0]['virtual_ro_id']": "60"
}
ok: [server1.dc2.com] => {
    "datacenters[mydomain][myhost][0]['virtual_ro_id']": "61"
}
ok: [server2.dc2.com] => {
    "datacenters[mydomain][myhost][0]['virtual_ro_id']": "61"
}
```

Is this probably what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @vladimir-botka. I have tested it locally and it worked :)